# Do I have the correct understanding of composition

Tags: composition

From what I read composition is when one object depends on another to exist. For example a tail cannot exist with out a dog.  Also, would it still be considered composition if I had a tail class that was used by both a class dog and a class cat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, composition is when a large thing (think whale) eats a smaller thing (think of a poor fish of some kind).

Your cat class *contains* a tail just like your dog *contains* a tail class. Both are examples of composition.

Comment: Thanks, would that make this a has a relationship?

Comment: Yep, `has a` is composition while `is a` is polymorphism (or subclassing).